# R - apply diff() function or equivalent self-defined function on multiple columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

currently have a `data.table` that looks roughly like this:

```
ID   Date         Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4
1    2020-03-01   AB     A33    250    12
1    2020-04-01   B      B25    NA     14
1    2020-05-01   AB     A44    270    20
1    2020-06-01   AC     C33    9     13
2    2019-09-01   X      C55    280    11
2    2019-10-01   K      C89    120    12
2    2019-11-01   A      C89    320    NA
2    2019-12-01   AB     A88    200    25
```

This data table stores the key `ID` and some corresponding variables. Some are type `char` and some type `numeric`. The table is sorted with `setkey(dt, ID, Date)` I want to compute the lagged difference for each numeric variable within each ID.

In my data I have the numeric columns extracted in vectors that look like this.

```
cols <- c("Var3", "Var4")
cols_indx <- c(5:6)
```

Then I want to add new columns with the lagged difference of the numeric variables `Var5` and `Var6` to my data.table `dt`.

I try:

```
# Doesn't work    
as.data.frame(lapply(dt[ , cols, with = FALSE], diff, lag = 1))
as.data.frame(lapply(dt[ , cols_indx, with = FALSE], diff, lag = 1))
as.data.frame(lapply(dt[ , .SD, .SDcols = cols], diff, lag = 1))
as.data.frame(lapply(dt[ , .SD, .SDcols = cols_indx], diff, lag = 1))
```

On my data none works and results in **r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)]: non-numeric argument for binary operator**. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this especially as I don't see a binary operator anywhere within this code.

However, once I excplicitly state either the colnames or the col indices, all works fine. Why is that? In my case I need to shift a long data.table with > 250 columns and then compute the lagged differences or all those columns and all that for multiple lag intervals. It is not manageable to define all selected columns by hand. What am I missing here?

```
# Works    
as.data.frame(lapply(dt[ , 5:6], diff, lag = 1))
as.data.frame(lapply(financials.dt[ , c("Var4", "Var5")], diff, lag = 1))
```

Additionally, one step is still missing. I want to compute the **lagged differences within each group** (defined by `ID`). When I try `diff` and a self-defined function **both** throw similar errors.

```
i <- 1
lag_names_diff <- paste(cols, "Lag", i, "d", sep = "_")

dt[ , (lag_names_diff) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - shift(x, (i), type = "lag")),
       .SDcols = cols, by = ID] 
# Error 1:
# r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : non-numeric argument for binary operator

# or

dt[ , (lag_names_diff) := lapply(.SD, diff, x = cols, lag = i, differences = 1),
      .SDcols = cols, by = ID]
# Error 2:
# x - shift(x, (i), type = "lag") : non-numeric argument for binary operator
```

... everything breaks down with the error message. I cannot seem to figure out what is causing this. Highly appreciate any pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems because `diff(any_vector)` returns a vector but length one shorter than `any_vector`.  See this

```
diff(1:5)
[1] 1 1 1 1
```

So if `diff` is to be applied on any variable in a table, one element has to be added in the result either at end or at start.  Although I am not sure of your expected outcome, still I presume this.  (I am adding `NA` to the starting of resulting vector.  You may add `0` as well, if so desired.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(cols, ~c(NA, diff(.)), .names = "{.col}_diff"))

  ID       Date Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var3_diff Var4_diff
1  1 2020-03-01   AB  A33  250   12        NA        NA
2  1 2020-04-01    B  B25   NA   14        NA         2
3  1 2020-05-01   AB  A44  270   20        NA         6
4  1 2020-06-01   AC  C33    9   13      -261        -7
5  2 2019-09-01    X  C55  280   11       271        -2
6  2 2019-10-01    K  C89  120   12      -160         1
7  2 2019-11-01    A  C89  320   NA       200        NA
8  2 2019-12-01   AB  A88  200   25      -120        NA
```

Or if grouped on `ID` is required

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(cols, ~c(NA, diff(.)), .names = "{.col}_diff"))

# A tibble: 8 x 8
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Date       Var1  Var2   Var3  Var4 Var3_diff Var4_diff
  <int> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <int> <int>     <int>     <int>
1     1 2020-03-01 AB    A33     250    12        NA        NA
2     1 2020-04-01 B     B25      NA    14        NA         2
3     1 2020-05-01 AB    A44     270    20        NA         6
4     1 2020-06-01 AC    C33       9    13      -261        -7
5     2 2019-09-01 X     C55     280    11        NA        NA
6     2 2019-10-01 K     C89     120    12      -160         1
7     2 2019-11-01 A     C89     320    NA       200        NA
8     2 2019-12-01 AB    A88     200    25      -120        NA
```

Comment: I'll give it a try in a few minutes. Thanks for your suggestion! Could you shortly clarify what the ```~c(NA, ...)``` and the ```(.)``` argument in the diff function exactly do? The output is excatly what I need, so yes :)

Comment: For `NA` I have added explanation in the answer.  See edit.  Regarding `.` in tidyverse fashion, it is actually shorthand for writing invisible function, where `~` replaces `function(x)` and `.` replaces `x` everywhere

Comment: Ah, that's neat. Still relatively new to R, so that might come in helpful in the future. Much appreciated Anil!

Comment: So, if I were to compute the lagged difference say by period 2, I would thus need to add ```~c(NA, NA, diff(.))```? I already noticed this behavior, but so far didn't see a way to combat this. Thanks

Comment: Exactly.  To combat this you can write an invisible function inside the `apply` group of functions as well>  Once I am sure of your requirement, I may show you how

Comment: Essentially, I have a large data set storing various numeric variables of interest and I need to lag them by (in my real data) by 1, 2, 4, and 8 quarters to get lagged differences for a regression setting. Unfortunately not all data points for each ```ID``` is available and thus NAs inevitably propagate through the data. Anyway, I compute the lagged differences in my quarterly data set by said periods (3M, 6M, 12M, 24M) and then join data from this data.table to my main data set via a rolling join.

Comment: I am not well versed with `data.table` though it is much faster.  However, you can give your problem I may propose strategy with `tidyverse`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230848/discussion-between-aimbotter21-and-anilgoyal).

Comment: Thanks again Anil!